# get loopValues of id in jquery function

Tags: jquery, html

I want to get values of an attribute In jQuery function when on click event happens, I have tried as following

HTML:

```
<c:forEach var="listVal" items="${status.nameList}">
  <div class="someName">
    <a style="padding-right: 41px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span></a><u><span style="cursor: pointer;" class="spanClassValue" id="spanValue_${listVal}"><c:out value="${listVal}"/></span></u>
  </div>    
</c:forEach>
```

jQuery Function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".spanClassValue").click(function(){
            alert($("#spanValue_"+$(".spanClassValue").html()).html());
        })
   });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be in the `this` context of your selector:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".spanClassValue").click(function(){
        alert($("#spanValue_"+$(this).text().trim()).text());
    })
});
```

or:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".spanClassValue").click(function(){
        alert($(this).text());
    })
});
```